# Render multiple objects in same EJS scriptlet pair

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I have two objects that I am trying to render via EJS. I am wondering if it is possible to render them in the same pair of scriptlet tags or if i have to render them in separate pairs?

I can successfuly render the objects currentDay and typeOfDay in separate scriptlet tags:

```
<h1>Today is <%= currentDay%>. It's a <%= typeOfDay %></h1>
```

But it does not work in the same scriptlet, only the first object will be rendered when I use:

```
<h1>Today is <%= currentDay, typeOfDay%> </h1>
```

Can I use one pair or isn't possible?

```
res.render('index', {
    currentDay: currentDay,
    typeOfDay: typeOfDay
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a JavaScript template literal:

```
<h1>Today is <%= `${currentDay}, ${typeOfDay}` %></h1>
```